# "Cutting to the chase"

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

I already know that `cut to the chase` is an idiom. Following is a example sentence

> I will cut to the chase.

and it means to get to the point without wasting time. But is it grammatically correct to say:

> Cutting to the chase, I am new at this thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's appropriate to use but only after some attempt at a more lengthy explanation or [circumlocution](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/circumlocution).  The idiom actually means something akin to "forget all I just said -- let me get to the main point."  For example:

> I was trying to get to my grandparents' house, and first I took Route 5 but there was too much construction, so I got off the highway and started taking back roads but these were closed with flooding, so I went back to Route 8 and traffic was terrible.  Anyway, to cut to the chase, I didn't get there until well after dark.

If you use it without any previous explanation, it implies that there would have been a long story, but you don't want to tell it.

> So you want to know how I got this scar?  I could tell you all the details ... but, to cut to the chase, it involved a very angry koala.

Comment: ok. I get all the things in your answer. maybe my question was a little unclear but I wanna know if I can use ` Anyway, cutting to the chase, I didn't get there until well after dark.` instead of ` Anyway, to cut to the chase, I didn't get there until well after dark.` in your answer. Is that grammatically correct?

Comment: @kittyCat - Yes the example used in the answer is just as grammatically correct as your rewording

Comment: I would say it as, "Anyway, to cut to the chase...", and not, "Anyway, cutting to the chase..." However, that's more of a preference based on location within the quote than a grammatical necessity.